# Netbeans PHP Application from Remote Server - Issue

Tags: php, netbeans, remote-access, remote-debugging, remote-server

I was using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 on Windows 8.1 to develop my PHP applications. There was no issue with it. But later on when I start using Netbeans (same version) on windows 7, Although the ftp connection was successful but it was giving error:

> Error while listing files /.

Answer (score 0):

After too many searches I found that by disabling features at firewall the problem is solved, All you have to do is just run a simple command in cmd.

1. Run cmd in administrative mode
2. Paste following command

> netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable

[image]

3. Now you are almost done!
4. Goto Netbeans->New Project->PHP->PHP Application from remote server
5. Follow other instructions and you are done! *(Note sometimes you will need to do that with passive mode)*